# C# connection string - Get from config section

Tags: c#

Here is a snippet of my app.config file.

```
<MyProject>
    <ConnectionStrings>
    ...      
    <Operational providerType="SqlServer" provider="" dataSource="<ServerName>" initialCatalog="<DBName>" security="" userName="<SomeUser>" password="<Password>" />
    ...
    </ConnectionStrings>
</MyProject>
```

In my C# code, I have this value available in some variable, like...

```
string OperationalConnectionConfiurationPath = "MyProject/ConnectionStrings/Operational";
```

How can I get my SqlConnection object out of this?

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom config section?  If not, this doesn't even come close to the built-in format.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to access data. So I need to establish a connection. How can I do that using the information available? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`connectionStrings` are a child of the `configuration` section.  Get rid of that `<MyProject>`stuff.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Operational" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME;User Id=USER_ID;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You can get the connection string by:

```
using System.Configuration;

var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Operational"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this solution, But I have been working on 10 yrs old project! At that time they setup this kind of crazy custom tags that I have to deal with now.

Comment: If you insist on keeping this format, you will need to create a custom configuration section.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx